# SQL - How to identify permutations of multiple key values

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, permutation

Thank you for reviewing.  I'm in desperate need of help and having trouble even being clear on the question below...

Using SQL 2008 I have a table set up with five columns.

Data effectively looks like this:

```
column1 column2 column3 column4 column5
T1      N1      A1      L1      S1
T1      N2      A2      L2      S4
T1      N2      A3      L2      S2
T1      N2      A1      L2      S4
T2      N6      A3      L3      S2
T2      N7      A3      L3      S4
T2      N7      A3      L4      S4
...
```

For records that have the same `column1` value, I want to identify each unique permutation of `column2` through `column5`.

I want to answer questions like this:

**Case 1**

How many records exist where

```
column1 is the same value and
column2 is the same value and
column3 is the same value and
column4 is the same value and
column5 is different
```

then

**Case 2**

```
column1 is the same value and
column2 is the same value and
column3 is the same value and
column4 is different and
column5 is the same value
```

then

**Case 3**

```
column1 is the same value and
column2 is the same value and
column3 is the same value and
column4 is different and
column5 is different
```

and so on.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in one query, by setting up a table of the permutations you want and some `case` logic in the query.

Here is an example with three columns.

```
with t as (
      select 'a' as a, 'b' as b, 'c' as c union all
      select 'a', 'b', 'd' union all
      select 'e', 'b', 'd'
     ),
     perms as (
      select 1 as col1, 1 as col2, 1 as col3 union all
      select 1, 1, 0 union all
      select 1, 0, 0 union all
      select 0, 1, 1 union all
      select 0, 1, 0 union all
      select 0, 0, 1
     )
select (case when p.col1 = 1 then a end) as col1,
       (case when p.col2 = 1 then b end) as col2,
       (case when p.col3 = 1 then c end) as col3,
       count(*)
from t cross join
     perms p
group by (case when p.col1 = 1 then a end),
         (case when p.col2 = 1 then b end),
         (case when p.col3 = 1 then c end)
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, I will try this as well and report back.  Very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. If you want to do it by hand, something like [group by](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) with multiple keys should do it. E.g. for case 1 you should do something like:

```
select column1,column2,column3, column4, count(column5) group by column1,column2,column3, column4
```

This should provide unique records for each unique combination of column1-column4. If you want distinct, then you probably need to do some preprocessing.

If you want a more flexible, probably a store procedure performing a group by could be a solution.

Comment: you could use `count(distinct column5)`

Comment: I will test and report back.  Thank you very much.